# Java overriding equals, array

Tags: java

Here's a code I'm working on, overriding equals. I've not tried compiling, but Netbeans is giving me a warning saying .equals on incompatible types.

```
public class Customers {
    private String name;

    public Customers(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean equals(String name) {
        return (this.name.equals(name));
    }
}
```

Main Class

```
public class TestCustomers {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       Customers cus = new Customers[1];
       cus[1] = new Customers("John");
       if(cus[1].equals("John")
           ...
    }
}
```

This works fine without using Array. But with array, it shows me a warning.

Why does it gives me a warning saying that .equals on incompatible types? Has this got to do with because of Type Erasures in Array?

Answer (score 4):

The complaint may be because

```
public boolean equals(String name)
```

doesn't really override the [`Object.equals`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)-method, since `Objects.equals` takes an `Object` as argument, and not a `String`. (This would probably be evident if you took the habit of explicitly writing `@Override` in front of the methods you intended to override other methods.)

Saying that a `Customer` can `equal` anything but a `Customer` seems like a really bad idea to me though. I would do something like this:

```
class Customer {
    private String name;

    public Customer(String name) {
        this.name = String.valueOf(name);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return (o instanceof Customer) && ((Customer) o).name.equals(name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode();
    }
}
```

And the main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Customer[] cus = new Customer[1];
        cus[0] = new Customer("John");

        // Compare against name
        if (cus[0].getName().equals("John"))
            System.out.println("Name equals.");

        // Compare against another customer:
        if (cus[0].equals(new Customer("John")))
            System.out.println("Customer equals.");
     }
}
```

Comment: What would be a better approach?

Comment: Your `equals` and `hashCode` assume that `name` is always not null.

Comment: I prefer a NPE (in the constructor) to funny things like: `new Customer(null).equals(new Customer("null"))==true`. Or put a if null check in equals?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Wrong 

public boolean equals(String name) {
        return (this.name.equals(name));
}

// Correct Way to override equals from Object.


// How about this implementation.

public boolean equals(Object obj) {


               if ( obj == null )
                    return false;  

               if ( obj ==  this )
               { 
                    return true;
               }

              if  ( getClass() !=  obj.getClass())
              {
                    return false;
              }
              Customer cust = (Customer) obj;
              if  ( this.getName().equals(cust.getName()))
              {
                    return true;
              }
              else 
              {
                   return false;
              }
 }
```

However using Apache Commons Equalsbuilder is the best way to go which does deep checking.
http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/EqualsBuilder.html

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as saying that your second alternative is *correct* since you say that a `Customer` equals a `String`.

Comment: `if (condition) return true; else return false;` can be written as `return condition;`

Comment: The `obj == this` comparison really should come first.  The `instanceof` and `getClass()` functionality overlaps.  The final four lines could be replaced with `return (this.getName().equals(cost.getName()))`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that what the compiler is complaining about is nothing to do with overloading (or in your case *trying to* overload) `equals`.

```
Customers cus = new Customers[1];
cus[1] = new Customers("John");
if (cus[1].equals("John")) {
```

The problem here is that `cus` has been declared as a `Customers` not as a `Customers[]`.  So the compiler is getting really confused about what `cus[1]` means and is (probably) giving it an undefined type.  Then it is saying that the undefined type does not support `equals`.

If you change:

```
Customers cus = new Customers[1];
```

to

```
Customers[] cus = new Customers[1];
```

you'll get rid if a bunch of error messages, including (I suspect) the one about `equals`.  Then you need to go back and address the problems with your definition of `equals` ... and other errors such as the fact that `cus[1]` will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`.

> Why does it gives me a warning saying that .equals on incompatible types?

I think you've managed to confuse the compiler by attempting to index a variable whose type is not an array; see above.

> Has this got to do with because of Type Erasures in Array?

No. The type erasure issue applies *solely* to generic types; i.e. types that involve type parameters.  You don't have any type parameters.

Answer (score -1):

1. Change the type of "`cus`" to "`Customers [] cus`"

   - `Customers [] cus = ...`
2. Add a String parameter type to the Customers constructor
3. Access item 0 (zero), not 1 (one) - First item in Java arrays is index 0.
4. Change the "equals" method parameter type to "Object" not String
5. Add the "hashCode" method - hashCode should be overridden any time you overide equals (see "Effective Java", Item 9
6. The equals method should have the following attributes (see "Effective Java", Item 8)

   - o1.equals(null) == false
   - reflexive (x.equals(x)==true)
   - symmetric; x.equals(y) can return true only if y.equals(x)
   - Transitive; if o1.equals(o2) and o2.equals(o3), then o1.equals(o3)
   - Consistent; o1.equals(o2) must always return same result (assuming neither object is changed)

"Effective Java" is a great book, well worth reading!